# Hibernate Projection throwing ClassCastException

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection, classcastexception, hibernate-criteria

## Hibernate 3x + Spring MVC 3x

### PART-1

**Generic Method**

```
// getAll
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> entityClass) throws DataAccessException {
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);
return criteria.list();
}
```

**Getting list in controller**

```
 List<GenCurrencyModel> currencyList=pt.getAll(GenCurrencyModel.class);
```

**Testing**

```
System.out.println("Type: "+currencyList.get(0).getClass()); 
System.out.println("Value: "+((GenCurrencyModel)currencyList.get(0)).getId());
```

**Result**

```
Type: class com.soft.erp.gen.model.GenCurrencyModel
Value: 1
```

---

### PART-2

**Change in Generic Method [Using Projection]**

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> List<T> getAll(Class<T> entityClass, String[] nameList) throws DataAccessException {
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entityClass);

ProjectionList pl = Projections.projectionList();

for (int i=0; i<nameList.length; i++) {
    pl.add(Projections.property(nameList[i].toString()));   
}

criteria.setProjection(pl);

return criteria.list();
}
```

**Getting List in controller**

```
String []list={"id","isoCode"};
List<GenCurrencyModel> currencyList=pt.getAll(GenCurrencyModel.class,list);
```

**Testing**

```
System.out.println("Type: "+currencyList.get(0).getClass()); 
System.out.println("Value: "+((GenCurrencyModel)currencyList.get(0)).getId());
```

**Result [java.lang.ClassCastException]**

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.soft.erp.gen.model.GenCurrencyModel]
```

1. Why this class cast exception , because
   **criteria.setProjection(pl)** return criteria and then Criteria returning the same list.
2. How to dynamically control this ?

update me !

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a projection to request `id` and `isoCode` so the result is a list of `Object` array with `id` at index 0 and `isoCode` at index 1.

Try casting each result to `Object[]` and check the content of the array.